# ModelForms for ndb model appengine (djangoforms not working for me)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms, app-engine-ndb

I am using webapp2, ndb model.
I was trying to use django model forms with ndb model. Following is the relevant portions from my setup:

**app.yaml:**

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest
- name: django
  version: 1.3
```

**Models.py:**

```
class SubTask(ndb.Model):

    task = ndb.StructuredProperty(TaskList)
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    start_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    end_time = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

**Forms.py:**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import TaskList, TaskCategory, SubTask

class SubTaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SubTask
```

**Handler:**

```
class CreateSubTask(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render_template('index.html', {'form':SubTaskForm})

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', IndexPage),
                               ('/subtask', CreateSubTask), ],
                              debug=True)
```

The error which i get is:
**AttributeError: type object 'SubTask' has no attribute '_meta'**

**My Question:** Is there a way i can use django model forms with ndb, or if i am making a mistake what is it?
If not django modelforms, does ndb model works fine with WTForms?

Attached below is the stacktrace:

```
ERROR    2012-06-23 03:25:58,770 wsgi.py:189] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/tdl/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from views import IndexPage, CreateSubTask
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/tdl/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from forms import SubTaskForm
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/tdl/forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class SubTaskForm(ModelForm):
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/forms/models.py", line 205, in __new__
    opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
  File "/homeproject/expts/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/forms/models.py", line 145, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: type object 'SubTask' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: as per NDB documentation you can use NDB with Django framework adding middleware to Django settings. Remember it has to be first middleware class in the list.

Comment: i am making a webapp2 app, just want to import djangoforms. will i have to write settings and middlewares? is there a cleaner process? could you point me to that documenation/tutorial?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview#intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the above comment, if you have not provided the settings in you main.py file, djangoforms won't render. Apart from that you need to add a middleware:

```
'google.appengine.ext.ndb.NdbDjangoMiddleware'
```

Doing the above two will fix things.

Answer (score 5):

Please don't use djangoforms -- it is not supported by the Python 2.7 App Engine runtime.

Comment: Hi Guido, are there any other recommended type of forms instead of djangoforms, that can be used with Python 2.7 App Engine runtime?

Comment: Guido, what is the recommended form engine for ndb models on python webapp2 appengine these days?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea. I no longer work on or use Google App Engine or NDB.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used django forms so might be missing some magic (and it might not make it work...), but this line looks wrong:

```
self.render_template('index.html', {'form':SubTaskForm})
```

You're passing the class to your template, rather than an instance of it:

```
self.render_template('index.html', {'form':SubTaskForm()})
```